# How to modify data during bulk insert from .csv files

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Every 10 minutes I get a .csv file from an external partner, that I need to insert into a SQL database. The goal is that
I afterwards can make a report that shows a graph with temperature during a date interval where I can see how the temperature
was during the day where the x-axis is time and y-axis is temperature.

The file contains:

UUID
Date
Time
Temperature

The date format is yyyy-mm-dd and the time format is hh:mm:ss.

How can I concatenate the date and time when bulk inserting?

Also the temperature is degress but comes in a format without a dot. For example 271 where it should be 27.1

Can I also change that during bulk insert?

```
BULK
INSERT [dbo].[temp]
FROM 'c:\input.csv'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 2,
CODEPAGE = 'ACP',
FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

Or can I just insert data like it is, and visually "change" it when doing the report?

Comment: Do you need to concatenate on the insert step? You could just do your formatting when you actually retrieve the data.

Comment: I agree with Rich. If you are concerned about read performance being affected, consider using Computed Columns with persistence enabled.

Comment: No, I don't have to concatenate on the insert step, and change the temperature. I just thought it would be easier than doing it in the "report layer". I'm new to reporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First import data to database table then change data as per requirements .

**for concatenate use :**

```
CAST(datecolumn  as DATETIME) + CAST( timecolumn AS TIME)
```

**for  temperature conversion use :**

1.

```
    Select Stuff(temperaturecolumn , Len(temperaturecolumn), 0, '.')
    From yourTable
```

Or

2.

```
 select cast(  cast(temperaturecolumn as decimal) /10 as decimal(4,2))
```